# Multiple Operating System on a Single Machine

Tags: linux, windows

By default I have Windows-8 installed on my machine, and I have installed Linux Ubuntu alongside Windows-8, Now on every start of a machine a grub menu appears where I can choose which OS to open (Windows-8/Linux-Ubuntu).
Now I want to install Linux-Kali on my machine alongside Windows-8 and Linux-Ubuntu.

Without touching Windows-8 and Linux-Ubuntu I want to install Linux-Kali, Because I have already installed many softwares in Windows-8 and Linux-Ubuntu.

Comment: Any chance you would consider using something like VMWare Player in windows and skip the native hardware install entirely?

Comment: As far as you have some space on your hard drive you could install one. This information on Kali Linux portal - http://docs.kali.org/installation/dual-boot-kali-with-windows is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install virtual box https://www.virtualbox.org/ and you can install any other OS as guest.

You can copy to any machine you are interested, and you can run both the windows and linux at the same time.